# Custom webpack resolver plugin change #meow to ./meow.js

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am trying to create a webpack resolver that will convert the import for `#meow` to the import of `./meow.js`. I have some basic code below that shows main imports `#meow` and the resolver should be converting all require statements to be `./meow.js`.

> meow.js

```
module.export = 'meow';
```

> main.js

```
import meow from '#meow';
console.log(meow);
```

> Resolver.js

```
module.exports = class Resolver {
    apply(compiler) {
        compiler.hooks.module.tapPromise('Resolver', async (init, resolveContext) => {
            return compiler.doResolve(compiler.hooks.module, init, './meow.js', resolveContext, () => {});
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example I got working with webpack 4.

```
class Example {
    constructor() {
        this.name = 'Example';
    }
    apply(compiler) {
        compiler.hooks.resolve.tapPromise(this.name, async (init, context) => {
            const callback = () => {};
            if (init.request.match('#')) {
                init.request = './meow.js'
                return compiler.doResolve(compiler.hooks.resolve, init, null, context, callback)
            } else {
                return callback()
            }
        })
    }
}

module.exports = Example;
```

Comment: I was looking for an answer literally for years, and you have resolved it (pun intended, heh) back in 2018! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is better to utilize [NormalModuleReplacementPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/normal-module-replacement-plugin/) to replace all the imports that are matched to some rule.

```
module.exports = function(env) {
  return {
    plugins: [
      new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(/(.*)#meow(\.*)/, function(resource) {
      // do what ever mapping
        resource.request = resource.request.replace(/#meow/, `meow.js`);
      })
    ]
  };

};
```

Comment: I am trying to write something more complicated then this. I need a real example.

Comment: can you elaborate? with my approach, you can rewrite imports. if you need more power, you can use the `normalModuleFactory`  hook, this is what the plugin uses under the hook. checkout the source-code https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/lib/NormalModuleReplacementPlugin.js#L18

Comment: I've tried to copy this and it still wont work for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53916959/compiler-hooks-normalmodulefactory-tap-cannot-read-property-tap-of-undefined